# margin auto two spans inside a div

Tags: html, css

sometimes I get tripped up on the simple things, I cannot seem to get this to work. I want the two spans to me auto margin centered within the div...

https://jsfiddle.net/5k4pnmf7/

```
<div class='foo'>
<span class='bar'>one</span>
<span class='bar'>two</span>
</div>

.foo{
  width:50%;
  margin:auto;
  background-color:blue;
}
.bar{
  width:30%;
  margin:auto;
  background-color:red;
```

Comment: Try [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: I agree with @AlexMcMillan here is a simple [pen](http://codepen.io/Froy/pen/yePXYb) of what it looks like in flexbox.

Comment: If the two `span`'s are centered in the `.foo` div, how much space do you want between the two `span`'s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using flex**

```css
.foo{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  width:50%;
  margin:auto;
  background-color:blue;
}
#main{
  margin:auto;
 
}
.bar{
  border:solid yellow;
   background-color:red;

}
```

```html
<div class='foo'>
<div id='main'>
<span class='bar'>one</span>
<span class='bar'>two</span>
</div>
</div>
```

**or just use text-align**

```css
.foo{
  width:50%;
  margin:auto;
  background-color:blue;
}
.bar{
  width:30%;
  margin:auto;
  background-color:red;
  display: inline-block;
}
#main {
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class='foo'>
<div id='main'>
<span class='bar'>one</span>
<span class='bar'>two</span>
</div>
</div>
```

or I don't know if you are looking for something like this

```css
.foo{
  display:flex;
  width:50%;
  margin:auto;
  background-color:blue;
  flex-drection:row;
}
.bar{
  width:30%;
  margin:auto;
  background-color:red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='foo'>
<span class='bar'>one</span>
<span class='bar'>two</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class='foo'>
<span class='bar'>one</span>
<span class='bar'>two</span>
</div>

.foo{
  width:50%;
  margin:auto;
  background-color:blue;
  text-align:center;
}
.bar{
  width:30%;
  margin:auto;
  background-color:red;
}
```

see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p6k7xz7u/)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you want the remaining white space (40% of parent width) to be evenly distributed between the two `span`'s and the spacing between the left edge of the parent and the first child `span`, and the spacing between the right edge of the parent and the right edge of second `span`.

One way of doing it is to specify the left and right margins on the first `span` to be 13.3333% (40%/3).  If you float the `span`'s, then the elements will be adjacent to each other taking into account the margin widths.

The second element does not need any margin values since it will be in the correct position to the right of the first.

Add `overflow: auto` on the parent to contain the floated elements.

```css
.foo{
  width:50%;
  margin:auto;
  background-color:blue;
  overflow: auto;
}
.bar{
  width:30%;
  background-color:red;
  float: left;
  text-align: center; /* optional... */
}
.bar:first-child {
  margin-left: 13.3333%;
  margin-right: 13.3333%;
}
```

```html
<div class='foo'>
<span class='bar'>one</span>
<span class='bar'>two</span>
</div>
```